# Is it possible to convert HTTPBearer.credentials to Pydantic BaseModel in FastAPI?

Tags: google-oauth, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI's `HTTPBearer` class to receive authorization tokens on request headers.

This is my dependencies file as per the FastAPI docs, which is used to retrieve the token on any request to the API.

```py
classroom_auth_scheme = HTTPBearer(
    scheme_name="Google Auth Credentials",
    bearerFormat="Bearer",
    description="O-Auth2 Credentials obtained on frontend, used to authenticate with Google services",
)


def get_classroom_token(
    token: str = Depends(classroom_auth_scheme),
) -> requests.ClassroomAuthCredentials:
    """Converts a json string of Authorization Bearer token into ClassroomAuthCredentials class

    Args:
        token (str, optional): Autorization Header Bearer Token. Defaults to Depends(auth_scheme).

    Raises:
        HTTPException: 400 level response meaning the token was not in the correct format

    Returns:
        requests.ClassroomAuthCredentials
    """
    try:
        # token.credentials is a JSON String -> want: pydantic Basemodel
        token_dict = json.loads(token.credentials)
        token = requests.ClassroomAuthCredentials.parse_obj(token_dict)
        return token
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail=f"{e}",
        )
```

And this is how I receive the token in my routes:

```py
@router.post("/test-auth", summary="Validate authentication with Google Classroom API")
async def test_auth(token=Depends(get_classroom_token)):
    try:
        gc_service_test = get_service(token)
        gc_api_test = ClassroomApi(service=gc_service_test)
        user_profile = gc_api_test.get_user_profile("me")

        response: responses.ListGoogleClassroomCourses = {
            "message": f"Auth Credentials Are Valid",
            "userProfile": user_profile,
        }
        return JSONResponse(response)

    except errors.HttpError as error:
      # handle exceptions...
```

Is there a way to specify the data structure of `token.credentials` like there is for request body?

This would make it easier to access properties as well as provide a format in the `authorize` modal on the swagger docs for other developers on the team, so they don't have to guess what the required properties of the Authorization token are.

This is my data model of the `token.credentials` as a BaseModel

```py
class ClassroomAuthCredentials(BaseModel):
    token: str = Field(..., example="MyJWT")
    clientId: str = Field(..., example="myClientId")
    clientSecret: str = Field(..., example="myClientSecret")
    refreshToken: str = Field(..., example="myRefreshToken")
    scopes: list[str] = Field(
        ...,
        example=[
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students",
        ],
    )
```

Comment: Can you tell what the class of that `token` object is? In other words, what do you get, when you put `print(type(token))` in the beginning of that function? EDIT: Nevermind, silly me. It is the return of `HTTPBearer.__call__`, so `HTTPAuthorizationCredentials`.

Comment: Please add a representative example of what `token.credentials` actually looks like (**without** posting sensitive information) to your original post.

Comment: HI @DaniilFajnberg I just added the correct BaseModel for the `token.credentials`. I have subsequently changed the logic slightly, but have updated the question. The system works as expected, I would just like to have the authorization header properties strictly typed like the json body is. It would help with testing in the swagger UI and returning error responses if the headers are missing keys or it is formatted incorrectly.